# Задачник с решебником по алгоритмам и структурам данных

Tags: алгоритм, книги, структуры-данных

Подскажите, где можно найти задачник по алгоритмам и структурам данных, к которому в сети был бы полный решебник? Нашел решебник к книгам Кормена и Скиены. Еще есть два классических учебника с обширной базой задач - Ахо и Кнут. Есть ли по этим книгам решебники? Или может есть какой сайт, где собраны задачи по тематике алгоритмов с приведенными решениями?

Comment: Решебник можно написать самостоятельно:)

Comment: Вообще-то, если Кнут - это "Искусство программирования", то решебник - вторая половина каждого тома :)